# Storing multiple instances of a symbol in an array Actionscript (Synthesia-based game)

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe

I am trying to recreate a piano based game like Synthesia. So I've made copies of a single note symbol in Adobe Flash & named the instances char0, char1, char2... to denote the different piano notes falling at different positions.

I want to store the instances in an array using the simple for loop before the initialization of the code. This is what I'm trying:

```
var charac:Array = new Array();

for(i=0;i<88;i++)
{
_root.charac[i] = char+i;
}
```

But its not working. This is the code I want to achieve but in an optimized form:

```
    _root.charac[0] = char0;

    _root.charac[1] = char1;


    _root.charac[2] = char2;
```

Any way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which version of AS you are using, this should work for AS2:

```
charac = new Array();
char0='0';
char1='1';
char2='2';
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
_root.charac[i]=_root['char'+i];
}

trace(charac);
```

S0, if you already created variables (char0...charX), they are accessible on this way (if _root is parent!)